# How to 'move' sygic maps to sd card

Tags: settings, gps, navigation

I've a new Lollipop smartphone (LG Spirit), i've Sygic Gps, but when i download maps, Android save it to internal memory. 
I've moved them to sd card (cut and paste), but when i start sygic it asks again which maps i would like to download. 
Is there an hack i can do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have been doing it wrong or maybe  the feature to switch to sd card storage was not yet introduced yet in the Sygic version.

According to [instructions](https://help.sygic.com/es/sygic-gps-navigation-for-android/tips-tricks/how-to-move-sygic-to-sd-card-android) given on Sygic help, try the the following:

> Depending on your device specifications and settings, Sygic files will
>   install either to your SD card, or in your device's internal memory.
>   If you want the Sygic files to be installed specifically to your SD
>   card, please follow these steps:

1. before installing Sygic on your device, select the option Store new apps on SD card

[image]

or

2. If you already have Sygic installed on your device, you can change the storage location at any time, via the settings in the application.
   Just go to Menu → Settings and tap on "Maps and Data storage" then choose the removable sd card option

[image] [image]